# Why can't I link games with my Google account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am playing Clash of Clans for the first time in a long time. Because of some problem, I uninstalled Clash of Clans and again installed it, but now my game data is not loading.

I've tried other games; they are not linking with my Google+ account, either. Is something wrong with my Google+ account?

Answer (score 1):

Either google play services or your Google Play games app is not updated, or they might not be working correctly. Just find out which one is causing problems and update the app. Most of the time I have seen this problem because of Google Play services not working properly on devices. If you are also having the same problems then do one of the following:-

1. Disable google play services from your phone's settings then a notification should appear -

> {Name of the game/app} will not work unless you update google play
>   services.

Click on it and update the app.

2. Uninstall all updates from Google Play services from settings then the same notification will appear and from there you can update the app.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can open the Google Play app and log in.
The problem might be that you are unable to sign into Google Play for some reason.